# Scraping a Dynamic Webpage in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am having difficulty scraping a dynamically rendered page. I have tried similar posts here for answers, but I know so little about javascript that I cannot understand them.

I want to scrape each table here: https://www.espn.com/golf/leaderboard/_/tournamentId/401056558

I have completed the one for leaderboard, but I can't figure out how to get the tables for Player Stats and Course Stats since they're dynamically rendered.

I am too ignorant of javascript to know where to begin. I've read V8 is a useful package, but I cannot figure out why.

```
# clears the R workspace
rm(list = ls())

# sets the working directory to the directory to the current working directory, which is where the
# output files will be printed
setwd(getwd())

# loads in xml2 for the read_html function
library(xml2)
# loads in rvest for the html_text function
library(rvest)
# for handling the dynamically rendered javascript
library(V8)

url <- 'https://www.espn.com/golf/leaderboard/_/tournamentId/401056558'
golf_webpage <- read_html(url)


# this block of code loads in and formats the leaderboard

# loads in the leaderboard data
leaderboard_text_html <- html_nodes(golf_webpage, '.Table2__td')
leaderboard_text <- html_text(leaderboard_text_html)

#creates a matrix with 10 rows for each of the 10 leaderboard columns and makes the number of columns the number of golfers
leaderboard <- matrix(leaderboard_text, nrow =10 , ncol = length(leaderboard_text)/10)

# transposes the matrix so each row is a golfer and each column is a leaderboard column
leaderboard <- t(leaderboard)
```

I want to figure out how to switch to the player stats and course stats tables to read them in.

Edit: I tried reading in all the the tables into a list of tables. It says there are 3 tables, which is the number I want, but only the last one (the leaderboard) is readable.

```
# loads the xml2 library
library(xml2)

# loads in the espn golf webpage as html
golf_webpage <- 
read_html('https://www.espn.com/golf/leaderboard/_/tournamentId/401056558')

tables_list <- golf_webpage %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the dynamic scraping question but it looks like there's a way you can grab the data directly eg) jsonlite::fromJSON('https://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/golf/pga/leaderboard/players?region=uk&lang=en&event=401056558'); jsonlite::fromJSON('https://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/golf/pga/leaderboard/course?region=uk&lang=en&event=401056558')

Comment: @Chris, it just gives me the following error:                                             
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       site.web.api.espn.com/apis/site
                     (right here) ------^

Comment: @oaxacamatt I thought of that and it didn't help me much so I came here

Comment: Have you checked out `RSelenium`? I found it to be easier to use this package when working with these kind of sites.

Comment: Yeah you'll have to copy the link text and remove the %27 as it's reading the quotation mark as part of the url...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From opening dev tools and then clicking on each tab within source webpage for `player stats` and `course stats` you see the following APIs calls which return json.

```
library(jsonlite)

stats <- jsonlite::read_json('https://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/golf/pga/leaderboard/players?region=uk&lang=en&event=401056558')
course <- jsonlite::read_json('https://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/golf/pga/leaderboard/course?region=uk&lang=en&event=401056558')
```

Comment: These both worked for me. I note you had problems with what was suggested in comments so see if the above makes a difference.